# [Pandas]how to get top-n% records within each group

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['@1','A',40],['@2','A',60],['@3','A',47],['@4','B',33],['@5','B',69],['@6','B',22],['@7','B',90],['@8
','C',31],['@9','C',78],['@10','C',12],['@11','C',89],['@12','C',88],['@13','C',99]],columns=['id','channel','score'])

     id channel  score
0    @1       A     40
1    @2       A     60
2    @3       A     47
3    @4       B     33
4    @5       B     69
5    @6       B     22
6    @7       B     90
7    @8       C     31
8    @9       C     78
9   @10       C     12
10  @11       C     89
11  @12       C     88
12  @13       C     99
```

Each channel has its own total number , I set a percent number = 80%

and I want to take int(channel'num * 0.8) nlargest , so it's will be

```
A channel take int(3*0.8) = 2
B channel take int(4*0.8) = 3
C channel take int(6*0.8) = 4

     id channel  score
1    @2       A     60
2    @3       A     47
3    @4       B     33
4    @5       B     69
6    @7       B     90
8    @9       C     78
10  @11       C     89
11  @12       C     88
12  @13       C     99
```

How can I do that , thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
a = 0.8

df1 = (df.groupby('channel',group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(int(len(x) * a), 'score')))
print (df1)     
     id channel  score
1    @2       A     60
2    @3       A     47
6    @7       B     90
4    @5       B     69
3    @4       B     33
12  @13       C     99
10  @11       C     89
11  @12       C     88
8    @9       C     78
```

Another solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_values('score', ascending=False)
        .groupby('channel',group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.head(int(len(x) * a)))
        .reset_index(drop=True))

print (df1)
    id channel  score
0   @2       A     60
1   @3       A     47
2   @7       B     90
3   @5       B     69
4   @4       B     33
5  @13       C     99
6  @11       C     89
7  @12       C     88
8   @9       C     78
```

Comment: What if I don't want to groupby ?

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that does not require the usage of `apply`:
Enumerate the rows in each group using [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and devide that by the group size to get the percentile the row belongs to in the group. Based on this you can create a mask to select the rows you want from the DataFrame:

```
key = 'channel'

# Group position for each row
group_idx = df.groupby(key).cumcount()
# Group size for each row
group_size = df.groupby(key)[key].transform('size')

mask = (group_idx/group_size) < 0.8
group_top_pct = df[mask]
```